# Can't get keepassXC to launch on startup

Tags: startup, system-tray, keepass, keepassxc

Ubuntu 18.04. KeepassXC installed via flatpak. I added it to the startup list, using filepath

```
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC.desktop
```

but it will not startup on boot. It does start quicker than normal when I manually launch it, so I suspect it's just not showing up in the system tray as it should.

Not sure what other data to provide. I do have various gnome extension installed but I'm not sure of the most efficient way to provide those short of typing out all 15 of them. If it's beneficial, please let me know of a concise/efficient method of exporting that list.

Comment: did you mark it in the *Settings* to be shown in system tray?

Comment: Yes, and to minimize to system tray. And I tried changing the icon from dark to light, logged off and back on. Still nothing. KeePassxc from the bionic repo works fine. But I wanted the flatpak bc it's much more up to date. Maybe I ought to try their ppa instead.

Answer (score 2):

To have the application autostart after login, copy the desktop file you are referring to into the folder `.config/autostart`. `.config` is a hidden folder in your home folder.

Comment: the autostart folder doesn't exist. I will create it and try

Comment: Your suggestion did not work. I rebooted twice. I notice when I copy it to this folder, it has a red padlock icon on it now.

Comment: My bad! It is .config/autostart, and it certainly exists on your system. I will correct my answer asap.

Comment: well, I've since switched to a PPA of keepassxc and that minimizes to tray and autostarts correctly. So I unfortunately can't confirm your answer. However, I think it's not so much it not autostarting, as it is not showing up in the system tray. Because with the flatpak, even when I minimized it or closed it, when I had the appropriate settings enabled, it would not show in the system tray as it should. So I'm thinking this is an issue with keepassxc flatpak version.

Answer (score 0):

I used a program called Startup Applications, found in the main Ubuntu repository, and manually added an entry and set the command to: `/usr/bin/keepassxc`

[image]

For some reason just adding `keepassxc` doesn't work for startup, but it works fine when you run the command in terminal. Not sure why it needs the full file path, but that worked for me.

PS: I installed from the PPA per [KeepassXC's blog](https://keepassxc.org/blog/2017-10-25-ubuntu-ppa/), because I was having too many issues trying to get the snap or flatpak to recognize the gtk theme.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc
apt update
apt install keepassxc
```

Please consider giving this an up-vote if you find this helpful.